# Create an item in a list automatically whenever an item in other list is created

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I have created a "master task list" in which all task items have a category (Category is also a list) which is assigned using drop down.

Now I need that whenever an an event is created in the "Event" list, as I assign an event item the category and save, then all the tasks from my master task list related to that category should be automatically generated in my "All Tasks" list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a simple designer workflow to create items in "All Tasks" list based on your category condition. You have to use "UPDATE LIST ITEM" as an action to create your workflow for "master task list".

Answer (score -1):

-Yo have to create the workflow on the associated list
for the workflow creation [visit this](http://plexhosted.com/billing/knowledgebase/226/How-to-create-a-simple-approval-workflow-in-SharePoint-Designer.html)

-through the list item creation workflow you can create the entry to another list